# Changing Radio Button Boder Color and Dot color in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a radio button in a .xaml file, like this:

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="True" Style="{StaticResource rdbResultsView}" 
                                 Template="{StaticResource RadioButtonControlTemplate1}"></RadioButton>
```

Style is:

```
<Style x:Key="rdbResultsView" TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

Template is:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RadioButtonControlTemplate1" TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Grid Background="Transparent" >
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" >
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledCheckBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PressedDarkCheckBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PressedLightCheckBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxCheckBrush}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledCheckBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledDarkCheckBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledLightCheckBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxCheckDisabledBrush}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Grid Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetLargeOverhang}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Ellipse x:Name="EnabledCheckBackground" IsHitTestVisible="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="32" Width="32"/>
                <Canvas Opacity="{StaticResource PhoneDarkThemeOpacity}" IsHitTestVisible="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Width="32">
                    <Ellipse x:Name="PressedDarkCheckBackground" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxPressedBrush}" Height="32" Width="32" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="DisabledDarkCheckBackground" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxDisabledBrush}" Height="32" Width="32" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                </Canvas>
                <Canvas Opacity="{StaticResource PhoneLightThemeOpacity}" IsHitTestVisible="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Width="32">
                    <Ellipse x:Name="PressedLightCheckBackground" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxPressedBrush}" Stroke="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" StrokeThickness="{StaticResource PhoneStrokeThickness}" Height="32" Width="32" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="DisabledLightCheckBackground" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxDisabledBrush}" Stroke="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" StrokeThickness="{StaticResource PhoneStrokeThickness}" Height="32" Width="32" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                </Canvas>
                <Ellipse x:Name="CheckMark" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="#009DDF" Height="16" Width="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" Grid.Column="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Margin="12,0,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

**Here i am able to change the color of the dot in radio button by changing the RadioButtonControlTemplate1 at:**

```
<Ellipse x:Name="CheckMark" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="#009DDF" Height="16" Width="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

**But here How can change the RadioButton Border Color(BorderBrush)?**

Answer (score 4):

Yes [it is possible](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/72653/173860.aspx) by making a copy of the style and template (Blend is very helpful with this)

Then edit the template and modify the color.

Comment: I don't have blend and also i am not familiar with blend. I have already saw URL which you have sent. In that URL we have another URL called RadioButton Styles and Templates[^] which redirects to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296247(VS.95).aspx. if you see this style(for radio button)  line called  <sys:Boolean>true</sys:Boolean> is giving error. Here we dont know that what "sys" means.

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer, it may be helpful for other people. I have changed the template `RadioButtonControlTemplate1`. In the template, we have an Eclipse with name `EnabledCheckBackground`. I deleted that eclipse and added a Border Tag like this:

```
<Border BorderBrush="#5D6892" 
        BorderThickness="4"
        CornerRadius="20"
        Height="32"
        Width="32"
        x:Name="EnabledCheckBackground"
        IsHitTestVisible="False"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"></Border>
```